# I am trying to accept and display array elements and this error is coming:

Tags: java

The Code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class array{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        //int arr[]=new int[n];
        int i;
        System.out.print("\nEnter Limit:");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int arr[]=new int[n];
        System.out.print("\nEnter Array Elements:");
        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            arr[i]= sc.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("\n"+arr[i]);
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

And The Console:

Enter Limit:3

Enter Array Elements:1
2
3
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 3 out of bounds for length 3
at array.main(array.java:15)

So any ideas how to resolve the issue??

Comment: What is `i` after your loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By assigning the value of variable `i` inside the loop, this value of `i` does exists outside, but outside (after the loop) `i` value's is equal to `n`.

Then `System.out.println("\n"+arr[i]);` will cause an exception, which named as the famous `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` since the size of `arr` is `n`, Hence the last index is `n-1`, by accessing the index `n` you are out of the array bounds.

By refactoring

```
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        arr[i]= sc.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println("\n"+arr[i]);
```

To:

```
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        arr[i]= sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("\n"+arr[i]);
    }
```

You will not access to the index `n`.